# Trigger an event when a set of images are loaded

Tags: jquery, events, triggers

I am loading images dynamically with JQuery. Some images can be big and I don't want to show any images unless all the images are completely loaded. So I have something like :

```
$('#mydiv img').load(function ()
{
    $('#mydiv').animate(
    {
        'width' : data.width, 
        'height' : data.height
    },800);

    $('#loading').remove();
});
```

So I though this would mean "when all the images in "mydiv" are loaded, resize the div and remove the "loading" item". But now I think that it actually means "when AT LEAST ONE image is loaded...".

Then how can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a variable outside the scope that keeps count when an image finishes loading

```
var fin = 0;
```

Then on each load function() you increment.

```
$('#mydiv img').load(function ()
{
    fin++;
    if(fin == $('#mydiv img').length){
       $('#mydiv').animate({
           'width' : data.width, 
           'height' : data.height
       },800);    
       $('#loading').remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks ! I think that's the best solution as it's uses very few memory.

Answer (score 1):

This would reside in a triggered event. For example a click event:

**Blanco**

```
var all_loaded = true;

$('#mydiv img').each(function() {
    $(this).error(function (){
        all_loaded = false;
    });
})

if (all_loaded) {
    $('#mydiv').animate({'width' : data.width, 'height' : data.height},800);
    $('#loading').remove();
}
```

**With click event**

```
$('#myButton').click(function() {
    var all_loaded = true;

    $('#mydiv img').each(function() {
        $(this).error(function (){
            all_loaded = false;
        });
    })

    if (all_loaded) {
        $('#mydiv').animate({'width' : data.width, 'height' : data.height},800);
        $('#loading').remove();
    }
});
```

If you really want the code to wait until all images you are loaded (which is dangerous to create an infinite loop), you can just keep re-looping the `.each()` until `all_loaded` is not longer equal to `false`. Like;

```
while (all_loaded !== true) {
    var all_loaded = true;

    $('#mydiv img').each(function() {
        $(this).error(function (){
            all_loaded = false;
        });
    })

    if (all_loaded) {
        $('#mydiv').animate({'width' : data.width, 'height' : data.height},800);
        $('#loading').remove();
    }
}
```

**Updated version**

```
$('#myButton').click(function() {
    var all_loaded = false;

    while (all_loaded !== true) {
        var all_loaded = true;

        $('#mydiv img').each(function() {
            $(this).load().error(function (){
                all_loaded = false;
            });
        })

        if (all_loaded) {
            $('#mydiv').animate({'width' : data.width, 'height' : data.height},800);
            $('#loading').remove();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I like the first code, but can you explain me what the folowing line means:  $(this).error(function (){...

Comment: `error()` is the "fail-version" of load. If `load()` failed, `error()` is thrown. Actually the first two blocks of code are flawed, as it will never set `all_loaded` back to `true`. Try to use the `while`-loop to keep checking until all images are loaded "error-free". I didn't test the code by the way. You might need to bind `load()` too in the chain, like so `.load().error(function() { ... })`

Comment: Thanks. Another solution is to set a timeout instead of a while loop so the function is called repeatedly.

Answer (score 1):

The code below will add an attribute 'data-loaded' for each loaded image. It will then check if the number of loaded images equals the number of images in #mydiv and execute the animation only after the last image is loaded:

```
$('#mydiv img').load(function ()
{
    $(this).attr('data-loaded', '');
    if ($('#mydiv img[data-loaded]').length == $('#mydiv img').length)
    {
        $('#mydiv').animate(
        {
            'width' : data.width, 
            'height' : data.height
        },800);

        $('#loading').remove();
    }
});
```